# What's the best approach to run a task using Timer only 5 times?

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

I'm using LibGDX. I want to run a task 5 times only after a couple delay of seconds. I have 2 options.

Approach 1

```
Timer.schedule(new Task() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mytask();
        }
    }
    , 10
    , 10
    , 5
    );
```

Approach 2

```
Timer.schedule(new Task() { // 1st time
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mytask();
        }
    }
    , 10
    );
Timer.schedule(new Task() { // 2nd time
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mytask();
        }
    }
    , 10
    );
Timer.schedule(new Task() { // 3rd time
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mytask();
        }
    }
    , 10
    );
Timer.schedule(new Task() { // 4th time
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mytask();
        }
    }
    , 10
    );
Timer.schedule(new Task() { // 5th time
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mytask();
        }
    }
    , 10
    );
```

I think Approach 1 is more efficient but for some reason it does not stop after the 5th time, instead it keeps going on. Help.

Comment: is it possible that you have a error in your first approach? There are only schedule methods with max. 3 parameters

Comment: The official site says schedule method allows a maximum of 4 parameters https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html#schedule-com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer.Task-float-float-int-

Comment: Sorry have looked at the standard implementation of java.util.Timer

Comment: You could archive this with the standard timer as follow `Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule( new TimerTask() {
            int run = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println( this.run );
                this.run++;
                if ( this.run == 5 ) {
                    this.cancel();
                }

            }
        }, 10, 5 );
`. I guess it's a bug in the first approach that the task doesn't stop after five times

Comment: Is it possible that the first approach executes the task exactly 6 times? A comment in the code says "Schedules a task to occur once after the specified delay and then a number of additional times at the specified interval."

Comment: You're actually right! It was executing 6 times. Thanks a lot mate. Post it as an answer so that I can choose yours as the correct answer. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the LibGDX implementation of the Timer schedules the Task and than again x times as expressed in the last parameter. The comment of this method says says "Schedules a task to occur once after the specified delay and then a number of additional times at the specified interval."
Therefore the first approach executes the Task 6 times and not as expected 5 times